# Rails 3 API with RABL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, rabl

I am trying to use RABL to create an API - but my setup is a bit different than the standard setup - as defined in their WIKI.

I have setup an API namespace in my routes:

```
namespace :api do
  resources :orders
end
```

I have my controller within /app/controllers/api/orders_controller.rb

and my RABL view within /app/views/api/orders/index.json.rabl:

When I try to visit localhost:3000/api/orders, I get the following error:

Template is missing

```
Missing template api/orders/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :haml, :rabl], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
```

However, If I create a new file called '/app/views/api/orders/index.html.erb' The view renders - but doesn't use RABL.

How can I make it so that it uses RABL?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

It is looking for the "html" format. Try adding `.json` extension to the URL or changing your routes to this.

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  resources :orders
end
```